# Compiler error related to expression involving list of shared_ptr

Tags: compiler-errors, c++14, shared-ptr, stdlist

I have two template declarations as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class A{
public:
T& getData();
//rest of public
private:
T& data;
//rest of private
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class B{
public:
using typAContainter = class std::list<shared_ptr<A<T1>>>;
B(int, T2&);
//rest of public
private:
typeAContainer C;
//rest of private
};
```

Inside the constructor definition for B, I use the following expression (for debugging):

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> B<T1, T2>::B(int I, data& rData){

  #ifdef DEBUG
  auto iter = C.begin();
  std::cout << (*(iter).get())->getData() << std::endl;
  #endif

}
```

For the expression `(*(iter).get())->getData()` I get the following compilation error:

```
error: no member named 'get' in 'std::__1::                   
__list_iterator<std::__1::shared_ptr<A<std::__1::basic_string<char> > >,     void *>'
```

My understanding is that `*iter` should give me an expression of type `shared_ptr<A<T1>>`. Invoking the get() method on the same should fetch me an expression of type `A<T1>*` (Pointer to `A<T1>`), upon which I try to invoke the `getData()` method using the `->` operator. I have also paid attention to the operator precedence in constructing the above expression.

Obviously, there is some flaw in my understanding. I would appreciate if some one could point this out.

PS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misread some things about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) and misplaced the parentheses in `*(iter)`.

The expression `*(iter).get()` is equal to `*((iter).get())` (this in turn is equal to `*(iter.get())`). That is, you attempt to use the `.` member access operator on the iterator and then dereference what `get()` returns. Neither of that will normally work.

Either do `iter->get()` or `(*iter).get()`.